# Performance impact of using activationStrategy replace everywhere

Tags: aurelia

In my Aurelia app it makes sense for me to *always* use `activationStrategy: replace` for all my VMs because I have third party slideshows etc that need to be re-initialised when switching views.

When navigating from one route to another `replace` is always used anyway, but in the rare cases where I navigate to the *same* route (with new data) I'd prefer if the entire VM just ran again.

So my question is; is this really bad for performance? Or can I safely set all my routes to `replace` and sleep well? :)

Bonus question: Is there a way to set a *default* `activationStrategy` so that I don't have to remember to set it on every single route I create?

Answer (score 0):

There certainly some performance issue with always using `replace` since the framework will have to go through the whole component cycle. It depends on case-by-case basic so I think you will have to measure to see the impact.

As to specify `activationStrategy` once, you can declare a class with `determineActivationStrategy` method like in the [documentation](http://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration#reusing-an-existing-view-model), and then have all your VMs inherit/extend this base class.